# Asynchronous alert that brings focus to underlying window with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a window_one that opens another window_two. I want to set up an alert that will return focus to windowOne, without requiring any user action, and without pausing the script. How can this be done for Chrome?

```
function mouse_down_action() {
    window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        frame1.close()
    });
    var frame1 = window.open();

    //frame1 has been opened, now writes script to it

    frame1.document.write(`

    <head id = 'Id'> 
        <script>

          frame1 = self.window;
          pop_under = ('https://www.reddit.com/'); 
          winfeatures = ('width=1700,height=900,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,status=0,directories=0'); 

          frame1.addEventListener ('mouseup', function () { 
              frame2 = window.open(pop_under, "", winfeatures) 

         frame1.addEventListener('focus', function () {
               frame1.close();
               });

          });
      </script> 
    </head>

    `);

};
```

Comment: where is this `alert`? in window_one, window_two, somewhere else?

Comment: It would come from window_one to bring focus back to it. I have an event listener set up to close the window as soon as focus is brought back but I haven't been able to bring focus back. The function window.focus() and window.blur() do not work with Chrome it seems.

Comment: I'm not sure web pages in general can demand focus like that - that would be annoying, right, if you hit a website that prevented you from changing your currently focused window/tab in your browser

Comment: I agree. Regardless, it is a project I have to do. I added the code above.

Comment: With all respect, I hope you fail, because if there is a way to do what you are trying to do, then I will make sure the browser I use does not have that feature :p

Comment: Haha yes, there is a way I'm attempting to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Sounds like potentially malicious behavior.

Comment: It's for advertising. Do you have any suggestions as for how to do this?